# Differences between .Bool, .so, ? and so

Tags: raku, boolean-operations

I’m trying to figure out what the differences are between the above-mentioned routines, and if statements like

```
say $y.Bool;
say $y.so;
say ? $y;
say so $y;
```

would ever produce a different result.

So far the only difference that is apparent to me is that `?` has a higher precedence than `so`. `.Bool` and `.so` seem to be completely synonymous. Is that correct and (practically speaking) the full story?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I've done to answer your question is to spelunk the Rakudo compiler source code.

As you note, one aspect that differs between the prefixes is parsing differences. The variations have different precedences and `so` is alphabetic whereas `?` is punctuation. To see the precise code controlling this parsing, view [Rakudo's `Grammar.nqp`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp) and search within that page for `prefix:sym<...>` where the `...` is `?`, `so`, etc. It looks like [ternary (`... ?? ... !! ...`)](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L4131-L4145) turns into an `if`. I see that none of these tokens have correspondingly named [`Actions.pm6`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp) methods. As a somewhat wild guess perhaps the code generation that corresponds to them is handled by [this part of `method EXPR`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L7128-L7134). (Anyone know, or care to follow the instructions in [this blog post](https://perl6.online/2017/12/23/playing-with-code/) to find out?)

The [definitions in `Bool.pm6`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/de4e82259be36ac9c97b56d594591ea796a1b131/src/core/Bool.pm6#L66-L100) and [`Mu.pm6`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/7b10a428a5565cf122218523c1bc28c14b3d63aa/src/core/Mu.pm6#L101-L110) show that:

- In `Mu.pm6` the method `.Bool` returns `False` for an undefined object and `.defined` otherwise. In turn `.defined` returns `False` for an undefined object and `True` otherwise. So these are the default.
- [`.defined` is documented as overridden in two built in classes](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/defined) and [`.Bool` in 19](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/Bool).
- `so`, `.so`, and `?` all call the same code that defers to `Bool` / `.Bool`. In theory classes/modules could override these instead of, or as well, as overriding `.Bool` or `.defined`, but I can't see why anyone would ever do that either in the built in classes/modules or userland ones.
- `not` and `!` are the same (except that [use of `!` with `:exists` dies](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/de4e82259be36ac9c97b56d594591ea796a1b131/src/core/Bool.pm6#L79-L81)) and both turn into calls to `nqp::hllbool(nqp::not_i(nqp::istrue(...)))`. I presume the primary reason they don't go through the usual `.Bool` route is to avoid [marking handling of `Failure`s](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f02856d3ecc11a11209f2def38b6ef8c341a52ff/src/core/Failure.pm6#L57-L72).
- There are `.so` and `.not` methods defined in `Mu.pm6`. They just call `.Bool`.
- There are boolean bitwise operators that include a `?`. They are far adrift from your question but their code is included in the links above.